# Audit says "resources are non-cacheable" but headers say they are

Tags: .htaccess, caching, http-headers

When I run an audit in Chrome, I get this warning saying some files such as style.css are expicitly non-cacheable:

[image: audit]
However the response headers returned cache-control:public.

[image: headers]
I don't understand much of cache configuration, but don't the headers show it's public. If not what is the line I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Cache-Control: max-age`.

From the [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> public: 
>         Indicates that the response MAY be cached by any cache, even if it
>         would normally be non-cacheable or cacheable only within a non-
>         shared cache.

See also [this page](http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/) and [Yahoo's recommendations on caching](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires).